# eclipse plugin for hadoop 2.4.1 version

Tags: hadoop, eclipse-plugin, hadoop-plugins

I have installed hadoop 2.4.1 which is working and i am trying to configure eclipse for hadoop. I dont see an eclipse plugin for hadoop 2.4.1 version. Does anyone know where to pick that plugin and use it eclipse.

I understand that most hadoop distributions would have eclipse plugin in it, but unfortunately 2.4.1 doesnt have that as far as i see.

Where could we get the eclipse plugin and what is the eclipse-plugin version for that

an additional question on this, i am seeing some .a files in hadoop/lib folder. what are those and how to open those, because i suspect it might have library jar files.

Answer (score 0):

There is no official eclipse plugin from hadoop project.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-1487

But it can be compiled as per the below tutorial

https://github.com/winghc/hadoop2x-eclipse-plugin

Also, check out Hadoop development tools (HDT) for official hadoop eclipse plugin support.

http://hdt.incubator.apache.org/